# Faster way to trim blank noised-space from scanned images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, optimization

I am working on scanned documents (ID card, Driver licenses, ...). The problem I faced while I apply some pre-processing on them is that the documents occupy just a small area of the image, all the rest area is whether empty/noised space. For that reason I wanted to develop a Python code that **automatically** trims the unwanted area and keeps only the zone where the document is located (*without I predefine the resolution for each document*). Well that's possible with using `findContours()` from OpenCV. However,most of the documents(especially the old ones) have unclear contour and their extremities are not clear enough to be detected. Plus, the noise in the blank space can be detected as contours too.So contours will not work for all the cases.
The idea that came to me is:

1. Read the image and convert it to gray-scale.
2. Apply the `bitwise_not()` function from OpenCV to separate the
   background from the froeground.
3. Apply adaptive mean threshold to remove as much possible of noise (and eventually to whiten the background).

At this level, I have the background almost white and the document is in black but containing some white gaps.

4. So I applied erosion to fill the gaps in the document part.
5. Read each row of the image and if 20% of it contains black, then
   keep it, if it is white, delete it.And do the same with each column of the image.
6. Crop the image according to the min and max of the index of the
   black lines and columns.

Here is my code with some comments:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def crop(filename):
    #Read the image
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    #Convert to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #Separate the background from the foreground
    bit = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)
    #Apply adaptive mean thresholding
    amtImage = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(bit, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 35, 15)
    #Apply erosion to fill the gaps
    kernel = np.ones((15,15),np.uint8)
    erosion = cv2.erode(amtImage,kernel,iterations = 2)
    #Take the height and width of the image
    (height, width) = img.shape[0:2]
    #Ignore the limits/extremities of the document (sometimes are black, so they distract the algorithm)
    image = erosion[50:height - 50, 50: width - 50]
    (nheight, nwidth) = image.shape[0:2]
    #Create a list to save the indexes of lines containing more than 20% of black.
    index = []
    for x in range (0, nheight):
        line = []

        for y in range(0, nwidth):
            line2 = []
            if (image[x, y] < 150):
                line.append(image[x, y])
        if (len(line) / nwidth > 0.2):  
            index.append(x)
    #Create a list to save the indexes of columns containing more than 15% of black.
    index2 = []
    for a in range(0, nwidth):
        line2 = []
        for b in range(0, nheight):
            if image[b, a] < 150:
                line2.append(image[b, a])
        if (len(line2) / nheight > 0.15):
            index2.append(a)

    #Crop the original image according to the max and min of black lines and columns.
    img = img[min(index):max(index) + min(250, (height - max(index))* 10 // 11) , max(0, min(index2)): max(index2) + min(250, (width - max(index2)) * 10 // 11)]
    #Save the image
    cv2.imwrite('res_' + filename, img)
```

Here is an example: *I used an image from the internet to avoid any confidentiality problem*
It is to notice here that the image quality is much better (the white space does not contain noise) than the examples I work on.
**INPUT:** 1920x1080
[image: Input]
**OUTPUT:** 801x623
[image: Output]

I tested this code with different documents, and it works well. The problem is that it takes a lot of time to process a single document (because of the loops and reading each pixel of the image twice: once with lines and the second with columns).
Is it possible to do some modifications to optimize the code and reduce the processing time?

Any suggestion is more than welcome.
Thank you.

**EDIT:**
*I forgot to mention that I already posted the same question in [Code review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/212391/optimize-code-that-trims-blank-space-from-images), but I didn't get an answer. So I flagged the question and asked the moderators to migrate it to StakOverflow. And since I didn't get an answer from the moderators, I decided to post it here because I think it is on topic here too. Once I get an answer in one of the websites, I will delete my question in the other website to avoid redundancy.*

Comment: Instead of keeping a list of indices, you could keep only the min and max indices. That would be a lot faster.

Comment: I'll change that, thank you

Comment: This question has an answer in code review stack exchange via [this link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/212391/trimming-blank-space-from-images)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my method, check it out:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("1.png")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#Separate the background from the foreground
bit = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)

nonzero = np.nonzero(bit)

minx = min(nonzero[1])
maxx = max(nonzero[1])

miny = min(nonzero[0])
maxy = max(nonzero[0])

res = img[miny:maxy,minx:maxx].copy()

cv2.rectangle(img,(minx,miny),(maxx,maxy),(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.imshow('bit',bit)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this does not seem to work with most of the examples I have. For example, look at [this example](https://imgur.com/0NJ4wcZ), I kept the background and just changed the document with another one from the net (for confidentiality reason). [This](https://imgur.com/a/1ptnO0P) is the output of your code, as you see, nothing changed; it is the same as the input. And [this](https://imgur.com/a/nH6xPlY) is the output of my code.

Comment: You can see in that image, there is a black line surrounding the image. I just give you a solution for a specific sample, card in completely white background. If you want a solution that fits all for your application, you need to make some changes.

Comment: I recommend to use `findContour` with some area condition.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem.. most of scanned documents have noise and the space is not totally white. I'll adapt you solution with my needs and use `findContour` as you recommended. Thank you

Comment: Har Bom, I posted a new code, in which I used `findContour` as you recommended. The results are almost similar to the results when using the first code, but it is much faster. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

After the exchanged comments with [@Ha Bom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8743494/ha-bom), I ended to a more optimized solution, in which I used `findContour` as he recommended. Here is the code that I ended to:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
def func(indir, filename, outdir):
    img = cv2.imread(indir + filename)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    bit = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)
    bit = bit[50:bit.shape[0] -50, 50:bit.shape[1] - 50]
    amtImage = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(bit, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 35, 15)
    kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    dilation = cv2.dilate(amtImage,kernel,iterations = 2)
    kernel = np.ones((25,25),np.uint8)
    erosion = cv2.erode(dilation, kernel, iterations = 10)
    bit = cv2.bitwise_not(erosion)
    _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bit,  cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    if (contours != 0):
        c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        print(x, y, w, h)
    final = img[max(0, (y - 50)):(y + h) + min(250, (img.shape[0] - (y + h)) * 10 // 11), max(0, (x - 50)):(x + w) + min(250, (img.shape[1] - (x + w)) * 10 // 11)]
    cv2.imwrite(outdir + filename, final)
```

In this code, I am not obliged neither to loop through every pixel of the image nor to keep the list of indexes. So it is much faster!
I am sure this code can be optimized more, that's why I'll not accept my answer.
Thank you all.

Comment: A better answer is provided in code review stack exchange via [this link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/212391/trimming-blank-space-from-images)